# output to console and file simultaneously in windows prompt

Tags: java, cmd

I want to save the output of **ipconfig** to a file a.txt as well as the console should print it simultaneously.

I am using below code :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K  " + "ipconfig > a.txt" | type a.txt);
```

The file is created but empty and the console is printing the output correctly.

Could any one point out where am I goingwrong and suggest me a piece of advice to go through?

Thanks a lot ...

Regards

Comment: replace `|` with `&`. Why are you starting cmd within cmd?

Comment: it does not work on replacing

Comment: You should look at the following post on SO that proposes `tee` commands on windows. It is outside of java but should solve your problem : [Windows batch: 'tee' command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239924/)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html) is what you're looking for.